# SSIS - split each string (incl. NULL) into rows in new table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an excel file containing rows with random text. Some of them only contain one word, others multiple and others are just NULL .

Now I am trying to make a data flow in SSIS where I create a new in table with only and ID and all words in one column.

So:

```
ID | Text
1  | food
2  | *NULL*
3  | tree car map
4  | water
```

Should become:

```
ID | Text
1  | food
2  | tree
3  | car
4  | map
5  | water
```

I have tried doing it with a Script Component ( [like in this link, what most people suggested on other posts here](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.be/2012/11/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html) ), but that didn't work. ( [A pastebin link to my code and my Runtime error here](http://pastebin.com/X32d2bqG/) )

Any ways to fix this? I would like it to be done 100% in SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how `NULL` values are being handled in the script. 
The method `Row.Hashtags.ToString().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None)` cannot process a `NULL` value.

To fix this, we can check for `NULL` values before using the `Split` function. Replace the code you have with this:

```
// Method that will execute for each row passing
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //Check if the value is null before string split
    if (Row.Value_IsNull == true)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.SplitID = Row.ID;
        Output0Buffer.SplitValue = Row.Value;
    }
    else
    {
    string[] SplitArr = Row.Value.ToString().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        // Counter var used the loop through the string array
        int i = 0;

        // Looping through string array with student names
        while (i < SplitArr.Length)
        {
            // Start a new row in the output
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();

            Output0Buffer.SplitID = Row.ID;

            // This is the splitted column. Take the [n] element from the array
            // and put it in the new column.
            Output0Buffer.SplitValue = SplitArr[i];

            // Increase counter to go the next value
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I used the inputs `ID` and `Value`, and the outputs `SplitID` and `SplitValue`. Rename them to your choice but remember to add them into the script component.

Answer (score 0):

A script component can definitely work.   However, the error message is not present in the stack trace you posted, so I can't help you debug your script.

The way I would handle this, though, is to import the Excel data "as-is" into a staging table, and then execute a stored procedure with a split function to pass the data along into the final destination table.